# How to make buttons rounded with Material Design Theming?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I want my button to have rounded corners like:

[image: Rounded Button] // Image taken from google

To achieve this with material theming in android is to set the: `shapeAppearanceSmallComponent` to have a `rounded` corner.

But setting `shapeAppearanceSmallComponent` also affects all other components such as `EditText` so now they are rounded as well.

So instead of setting it to `shapeAppearanceSmallComponent`, I created a `shapeMaterialOverlay`. Set this overlay to a `buttonStyle` and set this button style in the theme as the default button style.

It works but only for default buttons. If I needed a `TextButton` as such:

```
<Button
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>
```

The `TextButton` won't be rouned. So as a workaround, I created `MyTextButton` style which extends from `TextButton` and set the `shapeOverlay` there as well.

so Now if I need a `TextButton`, I'll do:

```
<Button
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.MyTextButton"/>
```

instead.

I will have to do this for all other button types. I was wondering whether this approach is correct and if not, can anyone guide me on how to properly do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please use Google document for `Shape Theming ` --- https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape/

Comment: @DickensAS the documentation doesn't actually include the scenario I presented above.

Comment: it is there `<item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>` under the title `Using shapeAppearance in the theme`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute in the layout.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/buttomShape"
        .../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="buttomShape">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

The only way to apply it to all buttons is to define custom styles for all the button styles as you are just doing. Something like:

```
  <style name="...." parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/buttomShape</item>
  </style>

  <style name="..."  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/buttomShape</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did as well (as I described above). I was wondering if that was the correct thing to do or is there a better way.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones For my experience there isn't a shapeAppearance attribute in the theme dedicated only for buttons.

Comment: ok then. Will probably accept your answer if no one else answer the question with a better one.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a background drawable on your button. The drawable could look like this:

```xml
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/blue" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

This will give you rounded corners for your button background.

Comment: outdated way to do a rounded button.

Comment: "All attributes from MaterialButton are supported. Do not use the android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means MaterialButton can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, MaterialButton cannot guarantee well-defined behavior." - Android Docs

Answer (score -1):

You know there is a site for creating custom layouts for buttons
here is the  [Link](https://angrytools.com/android/button/)

[image]

it is a auto generated Code you don't have to code. Maybe it will be helpful for everyone

Comment: Outdated way to make a rounded button.

Comment: "All attributes from MaterialButton are supported. Do not use the android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means MaterialButton can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, MaterialButton cannot guarantee well-defined behavior." - Android Docs

Answer (score -2):

Create a drawable xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:width="1dp" />
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#4c95ec"

        />

</shape>
```

Comment: this is the outdated way to do a rounded button

Comment: you should devote my answer if its wrong or not working, there is no way to say that this is outdated

Comment: if you haven't noticed yet, I already down voted it. And YES, it is outdated :)

Comment: i mean you should not

Comment: "All attributes from MaterialButton are supported. Do not use the android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means MaterialButton can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, MaterialButton cannot guarantee well-defined behavior." - Android Docs