# Displaying the button in recycler view with distance feature

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to make a feature like in the attached image. It will display a button on top of the recycler view with a distance of the items in the recycler view. As the user will scroll down it will show items that are far away from the user location. However, I do not know how to implement this type of button that overlaps the recycler view. Can anyone let me know please what is this feature known as? How can I search more about it. I have tried searching with "button overlaps recycler view" but nothing found that can help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: From your explanation, it seems you want to implement a floating action button!!!! This UI already exists in android studio

Comment: Thanks @Bristol I found it. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [`Extended Floating Action Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/ExtendedFloatingActionButton), what you could do is something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Displaying items 250 to 500 miles from you"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output is :

[image]

You could also take a look on

[Buttons Floating Action Button](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android)
Also this other way to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61055155/4385913

Comment: I've edited the answer so you have more options

Comment: Thanks, I will check them as well :)